# Relate textures areas of a cube with the current Oculus viewport

Tags: c++, opengl, oculus

I'm creating a 360° image player using Oculus rift SDK.
The scene is composed by a cube and the camera is posed in the center of it with just the possibility to rotate around yaw, pitch and roll.

I've drawn the object using openGL considering a 2D texture for each cube's face to create the 360° effect.
I would like to find the portion in the original texture that is actual shown on the Oculus viewport in a certain instant.

Up to now, my approach was try to find the an approximate pixel position of some significant point of the viewport (i.e. the central point and the corners) using the Euler Angles in order to identify some areas in the  original textures.

Considering all the problems of using Euler Angles, do not seems the smartest way to do it.

Is there any better approach to accomplish it?

**Edit**

---

I did a small example that can be runned in the render loop:

```
       //Keep the Orientation from Oculus (Point 1)
        OVR::Matrix4f rotation = Matrix4f(hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose);

        //Find the vector respect to a certain point in the viewport, in this case the center (Point 2)
        FovPort fov_viewport = FovPort::CreateFromRadians(hmdDesc.CameraFrustumHFovInRadians, hmdDesc.CameraFrustumVFovInRadians);
        Vector2f temp2f = fov_viewport.TanAngleToRendertargetNDC(Vector2f(0.0,0.0));// this values are the tangent in the center
        Vector3f vector_view = Vector3f(temp2f.x, temp2f.y, -1.0);// just add the third component , where is oriented
        vector_view.Normalize();

        //Apply the rotation (Point 3)
        Vector3f final_vect = rotation.Transform(vector_view);//seems the right operation.


        //An example to check if we are looking at the front face (Partial point 4)
        if (abs(final_vect.z) > abs(final_vect.x) && abs(final_vect.z) > abs(final_vect.y) && final_vect.z <0){  
          system("pause");
        }
```

1. Is it right to consider the entire viewport or should be done for each single eye?
2. How can be indicated a different point of the viewport respect to the center? I don't really understood which values should be the input of TanAngleToRendertargetNDC().

Answer (score 1):

You can get a full rotation matrix by passing the camera pose quaternion to the OVR::Matrix4 constructor.

You can take any 2D position in the eye viewport and convert it to its camera space 3D coordinate by using the fovPort tan angles. Normalize it and you get the direction vector in camera space for this pixel.

If you apply the rotation matrix gotten earlier to this direction vector you get the actual direction of that ray.

Now you have to convert from this direction to your texture UV. The component with the highest absolute value in the direction vector will give you the face of the cube it's looking at. The remaining components can be used to find the actual 2D location on the texture. This depends on how your cube faces are oriented, if they are x-flipped, etc.

If you are at the rendering part of the viewer, you will want to do this in a shader. If this is to find where the user is looking at in the original image or the extent of its field of view, then only a handful of rays would suffice as you wrote.

**edit**

Here is a bit of code to go from tan angles to camera space coordinates.

```
float u = (x / eyeWidth) * (leftTan + rightTan) - leftTan;
float v = (y / eyeHeight) * (upTan + downTan) - upTan;
float w = 1.0f;
```

`x` and `y` are pixel coordinates, `eyeWidth` and `eyeHeight` are eye buffer size, and *Tan variables are the fovPort values. I first express the pixel coordinate in [0..1] range, then scale that by the total tan angle for the direction, and then recenter.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer.

I think that the first point can be solved with:
OVR::Matrix4f rotation = Matrix4f(hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose);

For the second point, I can't find the conversion function from FovPort of a certain 2D position to the 3D vector, may be you mean that I must to implement by myself. Up to now, I've just create the FovPort with the function CreateFromRadians().

Comment: @Pelux: if you pass the entire pose to the Matrix4f constructor you are also going to get the positional data. If you just want rotation you should just pass the pose Rotation component (a quaternion). Re: FovPort, yes you have to implement it. Once you understand what the FovPort tan angles values represent it is rather straightforward.